# Lambda expression compare boolean as false or true

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

Is there a way to simplify the following code (Lambda expression compare boolean as false)

```
allUsers.Where(g => g.IsAMember == false).ToList();
allUsers.Where(g => g.IsAMember == true).ToList();
```

Comment: allUsers.Where(g => !g.IsAMember).ToList();
allUsers.Where(g => g.IsAMember).ToList();

Comment: I was writing a comment on your latest Q when it was deleted - you need to insert a call to `.Where(a => a.MemberHistories.Any())` before you do the projection with `Select`, to avoid making the member call against a null reference; then `.FirstOrDefault` can become `.First` and there won't be a possible NullReferenceException after doing that. Or, use a ternary operator in the projection to make `Member` null when there is no member history.

Comment: It was deleted because it was a duplicate :(

Comment: Member = a.MemberHistories.OrderByDescending(ash => m.MemberChangeDate).FirstOrDefault().Member

Comment: This is what I have

Comment: Could you please let me know how to update this?

Comment: I have re-enabled my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IsAMember` is a boolean (non-nullable one) then you should be able to simply do:

```cs
var nonMembers = allUsers
    .Where(g => !g.IsAMember)
    .ToList();
```

And

```cs
var members = allUsers
    .Where(g => g.IsAMember)
    .ToList();
```